# Python if statement with multiple clauses

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code im trying to create is to print a wavelength such as radio waves or microwaves based on the wavelength value input.

```
    userInput = input("Enter wavelength (m) value: ")
    waveValue= float(userInput)

if waveValue > 10**-1 :
   print("Radio Waves")
elif waveValue < 10**-3  :
   print("Microwaves")
elif waveValue < 7*10**-7 :
   print("Infared")
elif waveValue <4-10**-7 :
   print(" Visible light")
elif waveValue <10**-8 :
   print( "Ultraviolet")
elif waveValue <10**-11 :
   print( "X-rays")
elif waveValue >10**-11 :
   print("Gamma rays")
else : 
   print()
```

Any hints on how I can get the second if statement to work. Every input I put in just outputs radio waves because my arguments does not work properly.

Also there is 5 more inputs that I will have to use elif commands for.

Comment: Also there is 5 more inputs that I will have to use elif commands for

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped me with this. I havent been programming long, and really enjoy the feedback people give on this website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to use powers of 10 here?  Because the convention for "10 to the minus 1" for example, is 1.0e-1.  What you have in your code translates to "10 times -1" or -10, which I don't think you intended.

I would rewrite as:

```
if waveValue > 1.0e-1:
    print("Radio Waves")
elif (waveValue > 1.0e-3) and (waveValue < 1.0e-1):
    print("Micro Waves")
```

as a prior answer pointed out, it is also more efficient to order the answers so that one side of the comparison is not needed (those values have already been accounted for by earlier tests).

for example:

```
if waveValue < 1.0e-3:
    <not in current code>
elif waveValue < 1.0e-1:
    print("Micro Waves")
else:
    print("Radio Waves")
```

Comment: Changing it to 1.0e worked great, and i just had to switch most of the < to > and the program works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your approach for a small number of "break values". For a large number of "break values" you are better off to create a table with the break values and the corresponding action.

i.e., in your case, a table with wavelength and classification. First row containing 10e-1 and "Radio Waves", 2nd row containing 10e-3 and "Microwaves"

In code, you just loop though the until until you find the correct row for waveValue.

This is common in Tax Tables. As a bonus, you can store your tax tables in an external database instead of hard-coding the values in your program.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second statement is wrong.

It says waveValue >10*-1<10*-3  which I think is >-10 and < -30 and if what I say is correct then there can't be numbers bigger than -10 that are smaller than -30

Answer (score 0):

A list of tuples could work quite well here:

```
wave_categories = []

# Load up your data of definitions
wave_categories.append((1e-3, 'Microwaves'))
wave_categories.append((1e-2, 'Somewaves'))
wave_categories.append((1e-1, 'Radiowaves'))
wave_categories.append((1, 'Ultrawaves'))
```

Then your detection becomes a loop:

```
def find_wave(wavelength):
    for category_wavelength, name in wave_categories:
        if wavelength < category_wavelength:
            return name
    raise Exception('Wavelength {} not detected in list'.format(wavelength))
```

To make it work for lots and lots of categories, just add more data to `wave_categories`.

Comment: is .append create an module for appenidx?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but `wave_categories ` is a `list`, which has a method called `append()`, which allows you to add elements to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bisect` module for this:

```
from bisect import bisect
freqs = [10**-11,  10**-8, 4*10**-7, 7*10**-7, 10**-3, 10**-1]
names = ['Gamma rays', 'X-rays', 'Ultraviolet', 'Visible light', 
         'Infared', 'Microwaves', 'Radio Waves']
>>> names[bisect(freqs, 10**-2)]
'Radio Waves'
>>> names[bisect(freqs, 10**-4)]
'Microwaves'
```